# Python "ImportError: No module named numpy"

Tags: python

Okay so I'm fairly new to Python, I ran the commands

```
sudo easy_install pip
sudo pip install numpy
```

Afterwards, I typed python followed by `import numpy` and got the error `ImportError: No module named numpy`

Did I miss something? Do I need to add something to sys.path?

Comment: Just to rule out the obvious, did `sudo pip install numpy` complete sucessfully?

Comment: Did it actually install? Also, what versions of Python do you have installed?

Comment: `which python`? you might see something like this if pip was working on python2 and your env python opened python3

Comment: Yep, they all completed successfully. Which python returns a path to Version 2.7, If I run env, my PATH includes python 2.7

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I solved it, I had to add a path where everything was installed to my PYTHONPATH env variable. I don't know why the installer didn't automatically do that.

Comment: Joe, you should accept this if it solved your problem (it's fine to accept your own answer!)